# relacionar atributo de tabla anidada con atributo de otra tabla en POO oracle

Tags: oracle, poo, oracle-11g

Hola como dice el titulo necesito relacionar el atributo *Id_libro* de tabla anidada que esta en la tabla **Prestamo** con un atributo *Id_libro*  de la tabla **Libros** en POO oracle, una especie de llave foranea para que no haya errores de que en prestamo haya un libro que no corresponde a los libros existentes de la tabla libro, hacer esto en MR es sencillo pero con Programacion orientada a objetos no sé como hacerlo.

Esta es la imagen del modelo que estoy tratando de pasar a SQL
[image: Esta es la imagen del modelo que estoy tratando de pasar a SQL]

En estas dos cosas es donde tengo el problema, ya que no sé como relacionarlos.

```
--creo objeto con nombre pedidos_type
CREATE TYPE pedidos_type AS OBJECT(
    id_libro INT,              --<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DUDA COMO RELACIONO ESO CON EL IDLIBRO DE TABLA LIBRO
    fecha_p DATE,
    fecha_devolucion DATE,
    fecha_devuelto DATE
)

CREATE TABLE libros(
    id_libro INT NOT NULL,
    datos datos_libros_type,

    CONSTRAINT pk_libros PRIMARY KEY(id_libro)
);
```

CODIGO SQL ORACLE:

```
--/////////////////////////////SENTENCIAS PARA TABLA ESTUDIANTE//////////////////////////////////

--creo el varray telefonos_type de tamaño 5 y de tipo varchar2
CREATE TYPE telefonos_type AS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(20);


--creo un objeto llamado contacto_type
CREATE TYPE contacto_type AS OBJECT(
    correo VARCHAR2(50),
    telefono telefonos_type
)

--creo un objeto llamado direccion_type
CREATE TYPE direccion_type AS OBJECT(
    ciudad VARCHAR2(20),
    calle VARCHAR2(20),
    provincia VARCHAR2(20),
    cod_postal INT
)

--creo un objeto llamado nombres_type
CREATE TYPE nombres_type AS OBJECT(
    nombre VARCHAR2(20),
    apellido VARCHAR2(20),
    genero CHAR(1)
)

--creo un objeto llamado estudiantes_type que contendra a los otros objetos creados anteriormente
CREATE TYPE estudiantes_type AS OBJECT(
    nombres nombres_type,
    direccion direccion_type,
    contacto contacto_type
)

--FINALMENTE creo tabla estudiante
CREATE TABLE estudiantes(
    id_lector NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    datos estudiantes_type,

    CONSTRAINT pk_estudiantes PRIMARY KEY(id_lector)
);


--/////////////////////////////SENTENCIAS PARA TABLA AUTOR//////////////////////////////////

--creo un objeto llamado datos_nacimiento_type
CREATE TYPE datos_nacimiento_type AS OBJECT(
    ciudad VARCHAR2(20),
    pais VARCHAR2(20),
    anio INT
)

--creo un objeto llamado autores_type que contendra a los otros objetos creados anteriormente
CREATE TYPE autores_type AS OBJECT(
    nombres nombres_type, --uso el objeto creado en las /////sentencias de estudiantes///////
    datos_nac datos_nacimiento_type
)

--FINALMENTE creo tabla autores
CREATE TABLE autores(
    id_autor NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    datos autores_type,

    CONSTRAINT pk_autores PRIMARY KEY(id_autor)
);

--/////////////////////////////SENTENCIAS PARA TABLA LIBRO//////////////////////////////////

CREATE TYPE datos_libros_type AS OBJECT(
    titulo NVARCHAR2(50),
    editorial NVARCHAR2(50),
    area NVARCHAR2(50),
    anio INT
)

CREATE TABLE libros(
    id_libro INT NOT NULL,
    datos datos_libros_type,

    CONSTRAINT pk_libros PRIMARY KEY(id_libro)
);

--/////////////////////////////SENTENCIAS PARA TABLA LIBRO-AUTOR//////////////////////////////////

CREATE TABLE libro_autor(
    id_libro INT NOT NULL,
    id_autor NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_libro_autor1 FOREIGN KEY(id_libro) REFERENCES libros(id_libro) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_libro_autor2 FOREIGN KEY(id_autor) REFERENCES autores(id_autor) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT pk_libro_autor PRIMARY KEY(id_libro, id_autor)
);

--/////////////////////////////SENTENCIAS PARA TABLA PRESTAMO//////////////////////////////////

--creo objeto con nombre pedidos_type
CREATE TYPE pedidos_type AS OBJECT(
    id_libro INT,              --<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< DUDA COMO RELACIONO ESO CON EL IDLIBRO DE TABLA LIBRO
    fecha_p DATE,
    fecha_devolucion DATE,
    fecha_devuelto DATE
)

--creo coleccion de tablas llamado pedidos_table como tabla de tipo "pedidos_type" para despues anidarla.
CREATE TYPE pedidos_table AS TABLE OF pedidos_type;

--FINALMENTE creo tabla prestamos
CREATE TABLE prestamos(
    id_lector NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    datos_pedido pedidos_table,

    CONSTRAINT pk_prestamos PRIMARY KEY(id_lector),
    CONSTRAINT fk_prestamos FOREIGN KEY(id_lector) REFERENCES estudiantes(id_lector) ON DELETE CASCADE
)   
NESTED TABLE datos_pedido STORE AS datos_pedido_table_save;
```

Comment: ¿No prefieres usar una tabla normal en vez de una anidada? ¿Tienes una necesidad especial que requiera este tipo de tabla?

Comment: Tú dices que Prestamo sea una tabla normal sin objetos?  es que me pidieron que lo hiciera usando tabla anidada :l (NESTED)

Comment: Si, o sea que, en vez de que la tabla `prestamos` incluya una tabla en la columna `datos_pedido`, que esta mas bien apunte a una tabla *normal* separada. Porque es muy inusual usar tablas anidadas. No creo que se recomienden. Y de hecho, no estoy seguro que lo que pides sea posible con una tabla anidada.  ¿Se trata de una tarea, o es para un proyecto serio?

Comment: Es una tarea, pero en varias guias de materia he visto que usan tablas anidadas, como la de prestamo :o

Comment: Justamente, creo que una de las varias razones por la que no se recomiendan es porque no puedes definir constraints como la que quieres en tu pregunta.

Comment: :/ raios, no sé como lo haré entonces, me pidieron que usará por lo menos una tabla anidada en el modelo y en la tabla prestamos calzaba perfecto